# Template Specialization that specifies that the type is derived from a certain class

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming

I would like to specialize the NumberValue class in the example below.

```
class Number {};

class One: public Number {
    static constexpr int value = 1;
};

class Two: public Number {
    static constexpr int value = 2;
};

class Three: public Number {
    static constexpr int value = 3;
};

class NotANumber {};

template <typename T>
struct NumberValue {
    static constexpr int value = -1;
};

/* Need some template specialization here for classes derived from Number */

static_assert(NumberValue<std::string>::value == -1);
static_assert(NumberValue<NotANumber>::value == -1);
static_assert(NumberValue<One>::value == 1);
static_assert(NumberValue<Two>::value == 2);
static_assert(NumberValue<Three>::value == 3);`
```

I've tried a solution with concepts, enable_if, is_base_of, but i can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is `std::derived_from<Number>`. Use that to specialize your `NumberValue` class.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can set the `value` of `NumberValue` to `T::value` (which means `class One` should be `struct One` so that `NumberValue` can access its `value`) by detecting whether `T` is derived from `Number`.

The corresponding concept in the standard would be `std::derived_from`

```
template <typename T>
struct NumberValue {
    static constexpr int value = -1;
};

template <std::derived_from<Number> T>
struct NumberValue<T> {
    static constexpr int value = T::value;
};
```